# Compile C Code on Android Phone

Tags: android, gcc, compilation, android-ndk, toolchain

I want to compile and run .c Files that are sent to my AndroidApp.
I want to compile on ARM .c Files for ARM.
I am using a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2.
I have installed the Android SDK and the Android NDK
I have done this with the Terminal IDE, but I don't want to compile it manually from the Terminal.
Now I have downloaded the GCC for Android (android-gcc-4.4.0) and don't know how to add this properly to my Application and how to compile with it from inside the Java-Code.

I have read plenty things on the Internet about this, but none of them really helped me figuring out, how to do this

So my Problem is:
How can I use the Android/NDK Toolchain from my Android App, or any other toolchain to compile and then run .c files.

**EDIT:**
I now got the android-gcc unzipped right on my Phone in the files directory (data/data/.../files).
I want to call the gcc compiler on the phone to compile a .c file.
I tried to use:

```
String[] cmds={MainActivity.this.getFilesDir() + "/android-gcc-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-gcc-4.4.0", "-c", file_path};
String result = "";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
{
    result += line + "\n";
}
alert_dialog("Output", result); // Creates and displays an alert dialog
in.close();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    alert_dialog("Error", e.toString() + "\n" + e.getMessage());
}
```

This was my approach invoking gcc on Android, but i only get following Exception:
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command [...] 
Working directory: null
Environment null.

Does anyone have a clue how to invoke the android-gcc compiler correct on the Phone?

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

This not an officially supported scenario; no OS worth its salt would let non-privileged apps install executable code on the device willy nilly.

On a rooted phone, you might have some luck; but still, you'd need to put together a toolchain from scratch. NDK was never meant for this. There's no flavor of NDK that runs on ARM.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, but how does this one work then? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=en

Comment: Near as I can tell, they compiled some GNU tools for Android and bundled it with their app.

Comment: What an *insulting* nonsense. **Only** an OS worth its salt would let the *owner* of the damn device decide what he wants to run on there.  
Only lock-in toy operating systems for devices that for the user aren’t even computers anymore and treat the user like a mentally disabled person would ever come up with a concept as insane and totalitarian as disallowing the owner access to his *own* device.

Comment: No owner of a device who's worth her salt would work as root/Administrator **by default**. You're reading too much in my words - I didn't for a second advocate non-rootable devices. I advocated the principle of least privilege.

Comment: **Nobody said that**. It was your misconception from the beginning.

Comment: Your thoughts on the merits of locked down systems are irrelevant to the question, which was about Android. SO is not a forum.

Comment: Your attempts, to distract from the fact that your answer is still brutally wrong and you are spreading nonsense, are getting sad.